# What's the difference with SIZE_T and unsigned long?

Tags: c++, c

I'm curious with the difference with `SIZE_T` and `unsigned long`.

When I saw `sizeof(SIZE_T)`, I trace that through declaration tracing in VS.

Then, I watched them in `basetsd.h` file.

`typedef ULONG_PTR SIZE_T, *PSIZE_T;`

`typedef _W64 unsigned long ULONG_PTR, *PULONG_PTR;`

what's difference with them?

And why c language divide them?

Comment: It's not defined by either C or C++ but is in a MSVC header and is for platform / architecture portability of MS-Windows applications (note that some of these headers date back to the 1990s) - _"...The maximum number of bytes to which a pointer can point. Use for a count that must span the full range of a pointer...."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types

Comment: The range of `size_t` (and therefore `SIZE_T` I guess) is sufficient to hold the size (in bytes) of any object. The `unsigned long` type might not be. For example on 64-bit MS Windows, objects may be larger than 4 GiB, but `unsigned long` cannot represent the size of such large objects.

Comment: Also note that on MS Windows, `_W64 unsigned long` is a 64-bit unsigned integer type and `unsigned long` is a 32-bit unsigned integer type. (The use of the `_W64` macro is peculiar to MS Windows.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIZE_T` is a Windows datatype, not a standard type. As for the difference, it is that `SIZE_T` may not be an `unsigned long`. Take a look at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) which lists Windows datatypes. The entry for `SIZE_T` says:

> The maximum number of bytes to which a pointer can point. Use for a
> count that must span the full range of a pointer.
>
> This type is declared in BaseTsd.h as follows:
>
> `typedef ULONG_PTR SIZE_T;`

And `ULONG_PTR` has the following entry:

> An unsigned `LONG_PTR`.
>
> This type is declared in BaseTsd.h as follows:
>
> ```
> #if defined(_WIN64)
>   typedef unsigned __int64 ULONG_PTR;
> #else
>   typedef unsigned long ULONG_PTR;
> #endif
> ```

So it could be `unsigned long`, or it could be `unsigned __int64`. In your case `ULONG_PTR` and in turn `SIZE_T` are defined as `unsigned long` but this may not always be the case.

In your specific case, `ULONG_PTR` is defined as `_W64 unsigned long`, however I believe this is identical to `unsigned __int64`.